# HTML Canvas - Use toDataURL to crop a rotated part of canvas

Tags: canvas

I'm using a canvas, which includes a rectangle. This rectangle is rotated. I would like to use toDataURL to crop that particular area out of the canvas (see the picture), is it possible to do so ?

[image: My canvas, with the rectangle]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the code below:

```js
const sCanvas = document.getElementById('source');
    const sCtx = sCanvas.getContext('2d');
    const cCanvas = document.getElementById('cropped');
    const cCtx = cCanvas.getContext('2d');

    loadImage('https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcwIW.jpg', img => {
        sCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, sCanvas.width, sCanvas.height);
        sCtx.lineWidth = 2;
        sCtx.strokeStyle = '#00ff00';
        lineRect(185, 35, 70, 70, Math.PI/4);
        cropRotate(img, 185, 35,70, 70, Math.PI/4);
    });
    function loadImage(url, callback) {
        const img = new Image();
        img.onload = () => callback(img);
        img.src = url;
    }

    function lineRect(x, y, width, height, deg) {
 
        sCtx.beginPath();
        sCtx.translate(x+width/2, y+height/2);
        sCtx.rotate(deg);
        sCtx.rect(-width/2, -height/2, width, height);
        sCtx.stroke();
        sCtx.closePath();
    }
    function cropRotate(img, x, y, width, height, deg){
        cCtx.translate(cCanvas.width/2, cCanvas.height/2);
        cCtx.rotate(deg);
        cCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, -x-width/2, -y-height/2, img.width, img.height);
    }
```

```html
<canvas id="source" width="300" height="150"></canvas>
<canvas id="cropped" width="70" height="70"></canvas>
```

above cropped image displayed in another canvas, but of course you can export it to dataUrl or whatever you need

[(test image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcwIW.jpg)